# Asprise OCR- Language Issue in C#

Tags: c#, ocr

if anyone has Asprise OCR language lib for Latin and Cyrillic, I am currently on the evaluation version but for the purposes, I need to put in another language if anyone has an idea how I could do that. Code is in C#.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, [Asprise OCR and Barcode Recognition for C# VB.NET SDK Component API](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/c%23-sharp.net-ocr-api-overview.html) supports the following languages:

```
Language    Native name ISO 639 code
Croatian    hrvatski jezik  hrv
Czech   čeština ces
Danish  dansk   dan
Dutch   Nederlands  nld
English English eng
Finnish suomi   fin
French  français    fra
German  Deutsch deu
Greek   ελληνικά    ell
Hungarian   magyar  hun
Icelandic   Íslenska    isl
Indonesian  Bahasa Indonesia    ind
Italian italiano    ita
Malay   bahasa Melayu   msa
Maltese Malti   mlt
Norwegian   Norsk   nor
Polish  język polski    pol
Portuguese  português   por
Romanian    limba română    ron
Russian русский язык    rus
Spanish español spa
Swedish Svenska swe
Turkish Türkçe  tur
```

The evaluation version is able to recognize English (eng), Spanish (spa), Portuguese (por), German (deu) and French (fra). For other languages, please contact Asprise for assistance.

Reference: [Asprise C# VB.NET SDK Image to Searchable PDF Developer's Guide](http://asprise.com/ocr/docs/html/intro-ocr-sdk-library.html#languages-supported)